# Laravel ajax runs but no results

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing a life searchwhich should bring back results, ajax runs, it is not bringing any error messages and my pace.js is indicating that it is doing an ajax request correctly (bar fill to 100%) It is just not bringing me back any results.

Ajax:

```
function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/searching/' + search_value,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#results').append('<div class="alert alert-success"><div>');
            $('#results').html(data);

        },
        error: function(data) { 
            $('#results').html(data.responseText); 
        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }       
    });
}
```

master.blade.php ( search box inside nav)

```
<form action="/searching" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result');" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/searching/{search}', 'SearchController@search');
```

Controller:

```
  public function search($search_value) {
    $search_text = $search_value;
    if ($search_text==NULL) {
        $data= Business::all();
    } else {
        $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
        echo $data;
    }
    //$data = $data->toArray();
    return view('results')->with('results',$data)->render();
    }
```

//edit

above code gives me an alert with all the data like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"dasd","type":"3","email":"fsdf@fsdf.com","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":null,"created_at":"2017-06-15 11:02:32","updated_at":"2017-06-15 11:02:32"}]<table style="width:100%"> 
<tr> 
<td></td> 
<td>dasd</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

but doesn't append data or do .html

Comment: What happens if you dd($data) before returning the view? Also you may need to call ->render() on the view to get the compiled html correctly.

Comment: if I do dd($data) just before returning the view I get nothing, ajax runs and then nothing happens

Comment: You need to return a json response, like this: return response()->json(['data' => view('results')->with('results',$data)])

Comment: your code gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Forgot the brackets to make an array, edited my comment

Comment: nothing if I look at the preview of the post I get: Collection {#209
  #items: []
}

Comment: call ->toArray() on your $data variable.

Comment: use type : 'post' instead of method : 'post'

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to run render() on the response

Comment: thanks, it still doesn't work ;/

Answer (score 0):

Return a json response from your route like this:

```
$data = $data->toArray();

return response()->json(['data' => view('results')->with('results',$data)]);
```

you may need to render the view first, just call render() last.

```
return response()->json(['data' => view('results')->with('results',$data)->render()]);
```

Comment: gives me: trying to get property of non-object

Comment: is this correct view('results')? does the file results exists in resources/views?

Comment: yeap resources/views/results.blade.php

Comment: I would break down the method chaining then and start logging each piece out to see where things are going wrong. At this point it seems like it should be working.

Comment: if there's something wrong it's the controller right?

Comment: property of a non object indicates its in your controller, just don't know at what line yet.

Comment: if and else are definetely right because if I echo $data inside them I am getting correct response

Comment: if there is no match so if I enter for example !, response is []{data: "<table style="width:100%">
↵ </table>"}
data
:
"<table style="width:100%">
↵    </table>"

Comment: Yes try it with some dummy data to see if the route gets all the way through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146756/discussion-between-przemek-and-btl).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$form = $('#someid');// give this id to the form
$.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data, status) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data, status) {   
        $('#results').html(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
public function search($search_value) {
    $search_text = $search_value;
    if ($search_text==NULL) {
        $data= Business::all();
    } else {
        $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
    }

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

> It will give you Response in JSON

And You don't need manually convert it to array, because Laravel already do that itself...

And... Let me know, if you test it....

EDIT: You can always see ajax response in Chrome or Mozilla Developer tools (Network section)

Comment: I get : [object Object]

Comment: and in chrome network tab i get: [{id: 1, name: "dasd", type: "3", email: "fsdf@fsdf.com", logo: null, twitter_business: null,…}]
0
:
{id: 1, name: "dasd", type: "3", email: "fsdf@fsdf.com", logo: null, twitter_business: null,…}

Comment: [Object]
0
:
Object
api_key
:
null
created_at
:
"2017-06-15 11:02:32"
email
:
"fsdf@fsdf.com"
facebook_business
:
null
gallery_id
:
null
id
:
1
image
:
null
instagram_business
:
null
logo
:
null
name
:
"dasd"
twitter_business
:
null
type
:
"3"
updated_at
:
"2017-06-15 11:02:32"
user_id
:
1

Comment: Just Console.log(data) and you get all you need to draw your table!!

Comment: can you give me and example of how to outpu this? why this doesn't append ? $('#results').append('<div class="alert alert-success"><div>');

Comment: Man, this is your response.... JS Object... do what you want with it!! You need to get response from your ajax call, here is it))))

Comment: You need to loop on your object like this :: $.each(data, function(key, value){}); then console.log(key, value); you can see your object seperated... after this you need to manually draw your table like this way. FOR EXAMPLE:::: $('td.name').html(value.name) in your loop, to draw all your table